# Merging non-related git repositories

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-merge

I downloaded (as a zip file, not a git clone) an entire project from a github repository, made my customizations and then created a brand new repository in bitbucket (I've begun with the local git repository and made commits as I went, like 100 commits).

My custom project is not related to the master of the original open source project in a way that I'm not working on a branch. **Please don't judge me, since when I did it 6 months ago, I had no knowledge on the git process.**

Now, I want to take advantage of all of the bug fixes that were made in the original project for the last 6 months and I don't know how to do it. I believe I'll have to make a lot of manual and hard work, but I actually don't mind. I want to make it easier to update later, in such a way that I have to do this manual job only once. I just would like to have some guidance on this process.

Can anyone help me giving me an idea of the process to follow?

Comment: “Downloaded” with `git clone` or as a zip file?

Comment: By "made my customizations" did you:
 1. begin with the local git repository and make commits as you went
 2. begin with the local git repository and make one big commit
 3. or make all your changes and add *everything* as an initial commit

Comment: I downloaded as a zip, unfortunately. I've begun with the local git repository and made commits as I went, like 100 commits.

Answer (score 0):

With the understanding that you created an initial commit from a downloaded zip, then made commits from there, here is the general process I would use.

1. `git format-patch --root` to create a set of patch files representing each of the commits going all the way back to your initial commit.
2. `rm 0001-*.patch` to remove the file that represents your initial commit.
3. Somewhere else, perform a `git clone` of the original project, and change into that directory.
4. Identify the commit in the cloned repository that is equivalent to your initial commit.  If you downloaded a specific release version, you may be able to find a tag.
5. `git checkout -b mybranch <identified-commit-or-tag>` to create and checkout a branch at the identified commit or tag.
6. `git am <location-of-the-patch-files>/*.patch` to apply and commit each of the patch files.  If this indicates conflicts, likely you branched at the wrong point, or the zip file contained differences from the original git repository.

At this point, you can either merge master or rebase to master.  Either way, depending on how far your branch and master diverged, you may have a lot of merge conflicts to resolve.